# Django form DateField initial value not updating in Apache

Tags: django, apache, datefield

I have a Django form that includes a DateInput like this:

```
Fecha = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'),initial=(date.today() - timedelta(1)))
```

The idea is that every time you access the template that contains the form, it automatically shows the day-1 date.In my development environment this works as expected.However, I've noticed something strange in my production environment. The DateField initial value doesn't change unless I restart my Apache Server. For example, if I restart Apache right now my form will show 2015-02-26 as the initial date and will stay like that until I restart Apache again. I'm not sure if this is Django related or it has more to do with Apache configuration. Any suggestions or workarounds? Thanks in advance!!!!

Regards,

Alejandro

Comment: It could be the caching of either Django or Apache...

Comment: Thanks Selcuk, do you know where do I check both Django and Apache caching settings?

Comment: You could look at the relevant lines in `settings.py` for Django. For Apache you need to check httpd.conf: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
def get_yesterday():
    return datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
mydatefield = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'),initial=get_yesterday)
```

Your code would evaluate the date.today() function at server initialization and not at form initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is neither a django issue nor an Apache configuration problem, but rather a result of how and when Python evaluates code. Class attributes are evaluated as soon as the module containing a class is imported/brought into memory. So your form class's `Fecha` attribute is evaluated only initially when your app starts, and not evaluated again until your app is restarted.

To handle this, simply provide initial date values when your view instantiates your form object instead of in your form class definition. This will work because your view function executes every time you refresh the page:

```
import MyForm
def my_view(request):
    my_form_instance = MyForm(initial={'Fecha': date.today() - timedelta(1)})
    ...
```